# Can a muslim who follows Ahl al-sunnah wa al-jamaah, also follow some sufi teachings?

Tags: quran, sunni, sunnah, sufism

Can a muslim who follows Ahl al-sunnah wa al-jamaah, also follow some sufi teachings? those sufi teachings that don't violate Quran and Sunnah.

Comment: That depends on how you interpret or whom you mean by ahl al-Sunnah wa al-Jama'ah in first place. But with some kind of objectivity one should ask oneself if what sufis do is neither in the qur'an nor sunnah, is it still part of Islam? Allah said. "This day I have perfected for you your religion and completed My favor upon you and have approved for you Islam as religion." (5:3)

Comment: *"...follow some sufi teachings"* ... like what ? **"And whatever the Messenger has given you - take; and what he has forbidden you - refrain from. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty"**.[Quran 59:7](https://quran.com/59/7) . So you need to be specific about what  teaching exactly you are asking about.

Answer (score -3):

Of course. ..if a person can do that. ..he is a knowledge person ...and only possible with better filtration .because soofism is higher level

Comment: This looks more like a comment. See [answer].